# How to play a sound with a given sample rate in Java?

Tags: java, audio, sampling

I was wondering if there is a library or something to play a sound on a given sample rate (20–20,000 Hz). Actually, I found [something](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioFormat.html) but I'm not understanding how I can make it work!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's complete example not requiring any external library :

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class SoundUtils {

  public static float SAMPLE_RATE = 8000f;

  public static void tone(int hz, int msecs) 
     throws LineUnavailableException 
  {
     tone(hz, msecs, 1.0);
  }

  public static void tone(int hz, int msecs, double vol)
      throws LineUnavailableException 
  {
    byte[] buf = new byte[1];
    AudioFormat af = 
        new AudioFormat(
            SAMPLE_RATE, // sampleRate
            8,           // sampleSizeInBits
            1,           // channels
            true,        // signed
            false);      // bigEndian
    SourceDataLine sdl = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);
    sdl.open(af);
    sdl.start();
    for (int i=0; i < msecs*8; i++) {
      double angle = i / (SAMPLE_RATE / hz) * 2.0 * Math.PI;
      buf[0] = (byte)(Math.sin(angle) * 127.0 * vol);
      sdl.write(buf,0,1);
    }
    sdl.drain();
    sdl.stop();
    sdl.close();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SoundUtils.tone(1000,100);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    SoundUtils.tone(100,1000);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    SoundUtils.tone(5000,100);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    SoundUtils.tone(400,500);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    SoundUtils.tone(400,500, 0.2);

  }
}
```

Source : http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0499.html

Comment: Hi @slaadvak!On that code what does SoundUtils is?
`SoundUtils.tone(400,500, 0.2);`

Comment: `SoundUtils` is the name of the class the author is creating in its example (see `public class SoundUtils {` at the beginning of the example). You can reuse this class as is, like what you can see in the main method at the bottom of the example.

Comment: @slaadvak I wonder why the sdl crated as af should be opened(af)? Is it done to introduce the redundacny (our lovely syntactic salt). I like that by "sound" you mean a sine wave. This is really `a sound` (can you prove otherwise?) and does what is asked. Right?

Comment: @Val `open()` is called to acquire the "sound" resource of the system. It's similar to open a file before issuing reads or writes to it.

And yes, it is a real sine wave. Here is a sample of the content of the buf[] for a 1Khz frequency : `0, 89, 127, 89, 0, -89, -127, -89, 0, ...`

Comment: @slaadvak Do you mean that `file = open(name); open(file);` is typical? Where is the read/write? Regarding sine wave, I am not interested to know wheter it is real or not. I am interested to know how is it sound, requested in the question?